# Unable to install all gem files using bundler: receiving Could not find timeout-extensions-0.0.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, github, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I downloaded a application through github(https://github.com/jmopr/job-hunter). I'm quite new to ruby and this is my first introduction to the language. My goal is to get the application running on my machine. I could not find the ruby version the application was written on but for reference I'm working with.
[image: My enviorment settings]

When running bundler I get the error of:
"Could not find timeout-extensions-0.0.0 in any of the sources"

Below for reference:
[image: command line output for bundler]

In the gemlock.file we find the timeout-extensions listed too:
[image]
After looking through Google I found no useable answers so I came here.

Comment: Try running `bundle update`. You also may have to put `gem 'timeout-extensions'` in the Gemfile. This is unfortunately something that tends to happen when apps haven't been updated for 4-5 years.

Comment: This is a bad idea to write ruby code on windows. You will face some issues all the time. Use Docker at least